# Spring Boot Maven compile throws start tag not allowed in epilog

Tags: maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

I am trying to create Maven SpringBoot project to use spring restTemplate.
I get this code from https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/. When I run mvn compile I get the error start tag not allowed in epilog but got p (position: END_TAG seen ...\n\n

Here is the stack trace

```
   INFO] Scanning for projects...
  [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the 
  POMs:
  [FATAL] Non-parseable POM /Users/
  ../.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-bom/9.4.12.v20180830/jetty- 
  bom-9.4.12.v20180830.pom: start tag not allowed in epilog but got p 
  (position: END_TAG seen ...</profiles>\n</project>\n<p... @507:3)  @ 
  /Users/../.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-bom/9.4.12.v20180830/jetty-bom-9.4.12.v20180830.pom, line 507, column 3
   @
  [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
  [ERROR]
  [ERROR]   The project org.springframework:gs-consuming-rest:0.1.0 (..gs-consuming-rest-master/complete/pom.xml) has 1 error
  [ERROR]     Non-parseable POM ../.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-bom/9.4.12.v20180830/jetty-bom-9.4.12.v20180830.pom: start tag not allowed in epilog but got p (position: END_TAG seen ...</profiles>\n</project>\n<p... @507:3)  @ /Users/../.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-bom/9.4.12.v20180830/jetty-bom-9.4.12.v20180830.pom, line 507, column 3 -> [Help 2]
  [ERROR]
  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
  [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
  [ERROR]
  [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
  [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
  [ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ModelParseException"
```

Here is the POM

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-consuming-rest</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Please update the POM file as it looks different from the one in the tutorial.

Comment: What is the version of Maven and Java you use? Are you building it from Eclipse? What happens if you do it from the terminal?

Answer (score 2):

The error is not from your pom but from pom of jetty that resides in your local repository:

```
[FATAL] Non-parseable POM /Users/
  ../.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-bom/9.4.12.v20180830/jetty- 
  bom-9.4.12.v20180830.pom
```

So please check that pom and given it wasn't downloaded correctly just remove the whole folder `/Users/../.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-bom/9.4.12.v20180830`

and rerun the build

Comment: Thank you Mark. Your suggestion fixed the problem.

Comment: Doing that and restarting Eclipse fixed it, thanks!